# vertex ai - get online predictions using api ( image classification )

Tags: image-processing, google-cloud-vertex-ai

**resolved**   [here](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/aiplatform/latest/aiplatform/v1.predictionserviceclient#_google_cloud_aiplatform_v1_PredictionServiceClient_predict_member_1_) hard to find docs w detls

i thought the REST type instructions for submitting an image ( post b64 encoded version of the image ) would include detailed REST reference of req'd headers and post body.

instead , all i see is [the following](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/image-data/classification/get-predictions#api_1):

Use the Vertex AI API to request an online prediction. Your model must be deployed to an endpoint.

[image]

Where are the detailed specs or reference data on how i would POST from say node js to the model endpoint for a label classifier on the B64 encoded version of a photo?